# How to post model data to controller from view using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to check on some data from the database based on values in my current model in the view in order to redirect the page to all users or show a message to wait for the others also i need the function to be called every few seconds to check if the others submitted yet.

//i have tried using the $(this).serialize(); but it sends an empty model

```
 function yourFunction() {
    var model = $(this).serialize();       
 $.post('/Home/getmessage', model, function (response) {
    });
    if(ViewBag.submit==true)
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:2537/Home/Score"
  setTimeout(yourFunction, 5000);
  }
```

Comment: you need post model data to controller when users click the submit ? and when someone submitted will return message to user to wait and if no one submitted will return something from controller? is that right ?

Comment: yes i need to post data to controller when the user submits to check if others submitted yet and i need to keep repeating this check so that when all users submit i redirect all the open sessions to another page

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
function yourFunction() {
var data = JSON.stringify($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/getmessage",
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.Success)
                {                     

                }
            }
        });
 if(ViewBag.submit==true)
 window.location.href = "http://localhost:2537/Home/Score"
 setTimeout(yourFunction, 5000);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function yourFunction(){
var data = JSON.stringify($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/getmessage",
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.Success)
                {                     

                }
            }
        });
};

if(ViewBag.submit==true)
 setTimeout(yourFunction, 5000);

public ActionResult getmessage()
{
    return RedirectToAction("score");
}
```